# dateutil parser returns a bad date when it should raise a ValueError

Tags: python, parsing, python-dateutil

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
def convert_to_ddmmyy(date_string):
    try:
        date = parse(date_string)
        formatted_date = date.strftime("%d%m%y")
        return formatted_date
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid date format"
# Example usage
date_string = "13.75"
converted_date = convert_to_ddmmyy(date_string)
print(converted_date)
```

This prints 130623.

I want this to be printed as invalid or something along that lines, what changes I can make?
It has to be using parser as I am dealing with various date formats, but I need to exclude this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex to recognize the invalid format: the pattern `\d\d\.\d\d` rejects any string in the format `'xx.xx'` where x is a decimal digit. This deals with your specific case. The second expression deals with a range of formats as explained below.

```
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse

def convert_to_ddmmyy(date_string):
    # if re.match(r"\d\d\.\d\d",date_string): # rejects basic pattern xx.xx
    if re.fullmatch(r"\d*\.\d*",date_string): # rejects wider range of similar patterns
       return "Invalid date format"
    try:
        date = parse(date_string)
        formatted_date = date.strftime("%d%m%y")
        return formatted_date
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid date format"
# Example usage
date_string = "13.75"
converted_date = convert_to_ddmmyy(date_string)
print(converted_date)
```

gives

```
Invalid date format
```

Here's an explanation. `match` looks for a pattern in the string and returns True or False. `\d` means a digit. `\` is used to make this a control value and not look for the letter `d`; `\.` is needed to look for the decimal point because this is otherwise used in regex (to accept anything). `*` means none or more of the previous. So the second pattern looks for none or any digits, a decimal point (full stop), none or any digits. However `match` would reject `2023.12.12` (which might be a date) because it sees the patterns `2023.12` and `12.12`; but `fullmatch` checks for the whole string to match the pattern so would accept this string. Hope this is useful. Regex has lots of uses in checking and changing strings.

Comment: The use of regex will solve the problem in this scenario but I was looking for a generic solution. If there is any another format which may give same problem, we will have to handle that separately again. Instead of that I was looking for the reason of this behaviour, so that we can handle it better.

Comment: The reality is that this parser interprets 13.75 as 2023-06-13. The `dateparser` module also accepts 13.75. So exclusion seems the way forward. The regex expression could be 'tuned' to reject several unwanted formats without needing to exclude each one separately. . But you have to define what these formats are or otherwise define what formats are acceptable and use regex to pass these through. Your question says `I need to exclude this format` which is what the answer does!

Comment: If you change the expression in my answer to `if re.fullmatch(r"\d*\.\d*",date_string):` then it will reject any number of digits, full-stop, any number of digits so 13.75, 0.45, 12345,45567. .75, 3. would all be rejected. Maybe this is what you want. This shows how the Regex can be adjusted to reject any formats you define as unacceptable.

Comment: It certainly solves the problem, but a bit of insight would be appreciated.

Comment: See edited answer with more explanation of regex. You would need to check the parser sort code to see why it accepts 13.75 as a date.